# Extension method for classes implementing an interface

Tags: c#, generics, interface, extension-methods

I am trying to create an extension method for all classes that implement an interface `Iinterface` which will return a list of `T` where `T` is the original class. So basically something like:

```
public static List<T> Funct<T>(this T obj)
where T : Iinterface, new()
```

However this applies to every object, not just to `Iinterface` classes. So, I am trying to make something like `this Iinterface obj`, which would work but only if I use it as `myObj.Funct<MyObjType>()` I can not directly use it as `List<MyObjType> list = myObj.Funct()`, but not  . Is there any way I could have such a usage of an extension?

I am considering using a utility function or extending `Iinterface` to create something like this:

```
interface IExtend<T> : Iinterface
where T : IExtend<T> {}
```

Then I can make an extension function like this:

```
public static List<T> Funct<T>(this IExtend<T> obj)
where T : IExtend<T> {}
```

However before I do this, is there a way I could implement the function directly to `Iinterface` objects?

**Update**
Usage example:

```
public interface Iinterface { }
public interface Iinterface2 { }


public class MyObjType : Iinterface { }

public class SomeOtherClass : Iinterface2 { }

public static class Mine {


    public static List<T> Funct<T>(this T obj)
    where T : Iinterface, new() => null;

    public static void Funct(this Iinterface2 obj)
    {  }

    public static void Main()
    {
        MyObjType obj = new MyObjType();
        List<MyObjType> list = obj.Funct(); // the above mentioned function works in this case

        SomeOtherClass obj2 = new SomeOtherClass();
        obj2.Funct(); // uses the wrong extension function
    }

}
```

**Update 2**

I have noticed some answers and suggestions where the usage is different. So just to clarify:

I do understand that using a different structure can get the output. I also already have. However I was looking if there is a way to have a structure that can work for this specific usage. Main reason being this is the simplest usage I found and my main aim is to implement this functionality in the simplest way. 
So basically I am looking for the exact usage as `obj.Funct()` and `obj2.Funct()` without generics or parameters required to be passed.

Comment: Edit your question to show a complete example we could copy and paste in to visual studio of how you would use this extension method, and a situation where it shows up but you don't want it to. list out all type names and avoid using `var` in your example.

Comment: Point taken. Thanks

Comment: Your problem is not a problem specific to extension methods, any function's overload resolution would behave exactly the same, a exact match is considered a "better" match than a generic type match.

Comment: Well my main issue is that the first extension would apply to any class. The `obj2` was an example of one of the issues I may face. I also don't want `Funct()` showing up for objects of every class

Comment: My code smell radar is off the roof. When you run into situations like this, it's usually indicative that should take a step back and rethink your design. Also, without any more context, it's impossible to help you. What does the function do? Just create a list? Is there any logic?

Comment: I didn't provide much info or the question will get too long. List is meant to get list of all items from database. interface is used to provide info about the database. Both interfaces provide different sets of info which are used in different ways to get the same set of data

Comment: I gave interfaces rather than abstract classes to allow for the class to extend any other class

Comment: `obj2.Funct(); // uses the wrong extension function` - No, that's correct. It's using the more specific signature.

Comment: ok rephrase "it wasn't the intended function"

Answer (score 0):

Not the best thing, but you could do something like this:

```
public static List<T> Funct<T>(this T obj, Iinterface type)
    where T : Iinterface, new()

public static void Funct(this Iinterface2 obj, Iinterface2 type)
```

These second parameters are just here to help your compiler.
But, you will have to pass twice your object as parameters which is cumbersome.

```
public static void Main()
{
    MyObjType obj = new MyObjType();
    List<MyObjType> list = obj.Funct(obj); // still works as expected

    SomeOtherClass obj2 = new SomeOtherClass();
    obj2.Funct(obj2); // uses the correct one, now
}
```

---

But, the best solution IMHO, would be to change your extension's names.

A method that returns a list and the other that doesn't. They don't do the same job, obviously.

So, why are they named exactly the same ?

Comment: Thanks for your answer. However, If I am either ways mentioning a parameter in the function, I might as well mention a generic (the way mentioned in my question second para), considering it is far safer.

Comment: Regarding the method names, they do do the same job and both do return a list. I really simplified my code since it was spread over and would have been really huge to share.

Comment: @NevilleNazerane - "I really simplified my code since it was spread over and would have been really huge to share." - we don't care how large it is, if you are not providing the minimal amount of code to demonstrate your issue then you need to show more code. You need a [mcve].

Comment: The code is completely run-able showing the actual issue. what I meant was i removed every unrelated aspect to the issue.

Answer (score 0):

The whole point about using interfaces is to hide details of the implementation, so you should consider doing something like this instead:

```
public static List<Iinterface> Funct(this Iinterface obj) 
{
    var list = new List<Iinterface>();
    //Add your logic here.
    return list;
}
```

Then consume it like this:

```
MyObjType obj = new MyObjType();
List<Iinterface> list = obj.Funct();
```

Comment: I needed the reference to the original type. also will need to create new objects of the type. that is why the `new()`

Comment: @NevilleNazerane: Provide a more complete example then so we can help you.